# How to transform array into string where key of the parent array is together with values of the subarrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have following array:

```
[2007] => array(457,321,156);
[2008] => array(559,211,181);
...
[2013] => array(325,121,101);
```

How can I transform it just like the following string?

```
[2007,457,324,156],[2008,559,211,181],...,[2013,325,121,101]
```

I tried it, but wasn't able to put the key of the parent array together with the values of the subarrays in the string:

```
// This give me the values of the subarray without the key of parent array.
foreach($max as $k=>$v){
    $new.='['.$v.','.$medium[$k].','.$min[$k].'],';
}

// This give me a 'Uninitialized string offset' error.
foreach($resultMax as $k=>$v){
    $new.='['.$v[$k].','.$v.','.$result06[$k].','.$resultMin[$k].'],';
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (if I got you right):

```
$new = "";

foreach ($max as $k => $v)
{
    $new .= "[" . $k . "," . implode(",", $v) . "],";
}
```